# Is there a way for creating two zipped gremlin iterators with one advanced one position ahead?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I am trying to programmatically add edges to the graph.

The idea is that, I will zip two stream of vertices and if consecutive two meets some conditions, I will create an edge between them.

The problem is with the zipping though. I can't make it to zip two streams, with one stream advanced one position ahead.

```
(
    g.V().hasLabel("person").
    order().by("age")
    .as("x")
    .local(
        union(
            select("x"),
            select("x") // .skip(1)
        ).fold()
    )
)

==>[v[2],v[2]]
==>[v[1],v[1]]
==>[v[4],v[4]]
==>[v[6],v[6]]
```

The above works. But when I uncomment the `skip` part, I get

```
==>[v[2]]
==>[v[1]]
==>[v[4]]
==>[v[6]]
```

but I need:

```
==>[v[2],v[1]]
==>[v[1],v[4]]
==>[v[4],v[6]]
```

I am attaching the follow-up part for reference.

```
(
    g.V().hasLabel("person").
    order().by("age")
    .as("x")
    .local(
        union(
            select("x"),
            select("x")
        ).fold()
    ).sideEffect(
        project("first", "second")
            .by(unfold().limit(1))
            .by(unfold().skip(1))
        .coalesce(
            select("first").out("age_lt").unfold(),
            choose(
                math("second - first").by("age").is(lt(5)),
                addE("age_lt").from(select("first")).to(select("second"))
            )
        )
    ).none()
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with using a partitioning pattern that has this form (where "2" is your partition size):

```
g.V().fold().
  emit().
  until(__.not(__.unfold())).
  repeat(__.skip(local, 2)).
  filter(__.unfold()).
  limit(local, 2)
```

but rather than skipping "2" inside the `repeat()` you just skip "1" since you only want to advance the traversers ahead by "1", thus:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("person").
......1>   order().by("age").fold().
......2>   emit().
......3>   until(__.not(__.unfold())).
......4>   repeat(__.skip(local,1)).
......5>   filter(__.unfold()).
......6>   limit(local,2)
==>[v[2],v[1]]
==>[v[1],v[4]]
==>[v[4],v[6]]
==>[v[6]]
```

Then, just get rid of any trailing unpaired items:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("person").
......1>   order().by("age").fold().
......2>   emit().
......3>   until(__.not(__.unfold())).
......4>   repeat(__.skip(local,1)).
......5>   filter(__.unfold()).
......6>   limit(local,2).
......7>   filter(count(local).is(2))
==>[v[2],v[1]]
==>[v[1],v[4]]
==>[v[4],v[6]]
```

Comment: It's super cool! Thank you! Do you have other common gremlin traversal patterns written down somewhere? I've googled for "partitioning pattern", but I didn't led me to anything. Are there any resources you recommend for learning gremlin? Right now I use gremlin recipes from Apache TinkerPop official page and Kelvin Lawrence practical gremlin.

Comment: "patterns" are documented in Gremlin Recipes: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/ - if you haven't checked that out yet, I'd read that start to end. I've called it a "partitioning pattern" only just realizing that I've only referred to it as such in a talk I gave at DataStax Accelerate https://www.datastax.com/resources/video/datastax-accelerate-2019-extending-gremlin-foundational-steps - i probably should write that up some time as a recipe.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you pairs of consecutive vertices:

```
g.V().hasLabel("person").order().by("age").store("x").local(
    select(all,"x").tail(local, 2)
).skip(1)
```

Note the skip at the end to filter out the first single vertex "pair".

Comment: Thanks! While this obviously works, could you elaborate on the performance of this? I've unwrapped the query and it seems to always select the last two items from the list that is growing with each step. Do you know how the actual graph databases handle those?

Comment: I tested my query on 10k vertices against the one suggested by Stephan, and mine was almost 2 times faster. Since you already accepted his answer you can at least upvote mine.

Comment: I would do it, but this account is to young to upvote - stack overflow does not allow me to :<. Good to know, though! Thanks!